# How to popState back in AJAX navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pushstate, popstate

I'm trying to create AJAX navigation and running into issues with popState. Below is a function that pushStates the pageName (loads the specified div from content.html to .mainwrap as well). There is a self-invoking function that parses the url and determines what to load, and there is a popstate event handler inside it. Lastly is a click handler for  elements with a data-page attribute to make them 'ajaxified'. How am I going about this wrong?

```
function loadPageContent(pageName){
  $('.mainwrap').animate({opacity: 0}, 250, function(){
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).load('content.html #' + pageName, function(){
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: 'fade'
      });
      vertCenter();
      $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 250);
    });
  });
  history.pushState({}, null, "#"+pageName);
}

$(function() {
  var lastPage;
  (function() {

    var url = document.URL,
    loadPage = url.split("#"),
    data;

    if(loadPage[1]) {
      data = loadPage[1];
    } else {
      data = "home";
    }
    loadPageContent(data);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
      console.log('popstate fired!');
      loadPageContent(lastPage);
      }); 
  }());

$(document).on('click', 'a[data-page]', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  lastPage = page;
  var page = $(this).attr('data-page')
  loadPageContent(page);
  return false;
  });
});
```

EDIT: As suggested I've placed 'var lastPage' between the two function rather than inside the two. Still not fixed. The url I'm getting on 'back' is /#undefined

Comment: Note that the ```lastPage``` variable is not reachable from the click handler.

Comment: Any advice where I put it? lastPage is how I'm trying to keep track of the page to go back to when the 'back'/'next' browser buttons are pressed.

Comment: Why don't you shift it up one line, and place it between the functions.